# cloud-init not working for NoCloud DataSource

Tags: cloud, datasource, cloud-init

I am trying to boot the instance with NoCloud datasource.
But everytime the instance comes up it is try to connect to the network and metadata service.

logs:
2015-08-17 15:48:58,115 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed [0/120s]: request error [HTTPConnectionPool(host='169.254.169.254', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id (Caused by : [Errno 111] Connection refused)]

I have created a drive with meta-data and user-data:

meta-data:
instance-id: iid-local01
local-hostname: cloudimg

user-data:

#cloud-config
write_files:
  - path: /test.txt
    content: |
      Here is a line

But the file is not getting created. Can you help in solving this issue? Or in disabling the cloud-init from contacting the metadata services.

Answer (score 1):

Old, But I hit the same kind of issue today because CentOS7 is still using cloud-init 18.2. Taking care of selecting correct version on the cloud-init doc (I did'nt first), I found that the label must be in lowercase "cidata".

If wrong or no label, your device will be ignored and cloud-init will fallback to network-based datasources (EC2,OS, etc...).

Feel free to use my sample script here as it will generate a vfat img containing your user-data and meta-data files. Then attach it to your VM.

Tested with current ubuntu and CentOS cloud images.

https://github.com/BrHal/CloudInit

Comment: Thanks for the script. It did not solve my problem, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673736/cannot-login-to-running-libvirt-virtual-machine-from-qcow2-cloud-init-image , but it did eliminate one source of potential errors, so now I can continue troubleshooting other parts of my process.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your issue is that the attached disk is simply not being created correctly so that cloud-init will identify it.  There is more information in the [documentation](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html).

[cloud-localds](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cloud-utils-dev/cloud-utils/trunk/view/head:/bin/cloud-localds) is a pretty much stand-alone tool available from the [cloud-utils](https://launchpad.net/cloud-utils) package that can aid in making a usable NoCloud datasource.  Its usage looks like this, provided a 'disk1.img' file that contains a image with cloud-init installed.

```
$ cat my-user-data
#cloud-config
password: passw0rd
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True

$ echo "instance-id: $(uuidgen || echo i-abcdefg)" > my-meta-data
$ cloud-localds my-seed.img my-user-data my-meta-data
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm \
    -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 \
    -drive file=disk1.img,if=virtio -drive file=my-seed.img,if=virtio

$ ssh -p 2222 ubuntu@localhost
```

If this is not working correctly for you, please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+filebug)

Comment: **broken link**: [cloud-localds](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cloud-utils-dev/cloud-utils/trunk/view/head:/bin/cloud-localds)